# Android animation for visibility and invisibity of view

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to put animation like - A view is first invisible mode,,, on button click it will be visible and slide up slowly and stay there for a moment approximately 5 seconds and then after it will slide down with animation and again move to invisible state.
Please anyone can help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: You need Alpha animation followed by Translate animation and vice verse.

Comment: Will you please elaborate how to use alpha animation and translate animation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you need is **two translate animations** with a **time gap of 5000 milliseconds** between the two, **and make the view INVISIBLE** , before and after the start of animation..

Let us consider your Button is named as `bt` and the view is TextView which is named as `tv`.

Follow the steps below to perform the animation as you mentioned :

**Create the layout file named as `activity_main.xml` which looks as below :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Now Create animation file named as `anim_ex.xml` in your `res->anim` directory in your project which looks as below :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <!--Use two translate animations with a time gap of 5000 milliseconds-->
    <!-- Use startOffset to provide delay between the animations -->
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:toYDelta="-25%p" />
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="5000"
        android:toYDelta="25%p" />
    </set>
```

**Below is the documented(wherever needed) JAVA file(`MainActivity.java`) :**

```
package com.example.anim;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AnimationListener {

    Animation anim;
    TextView tv;
    Button bt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.anim_ex); //Load the animation from the xml file
        anim.setAnimationListener(this); //Set Animation Listener
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Make the textview visible on button click
                tv.startAnimation(anim);//start the animation

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tv.clearAnimation();//Clear Animation when animation ends
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//Make textview invisible again

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanx.. I want exactly this kind of animation. Delay between two animation.

Answer (score 0):

animation grow_from_bottom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

animation close_to_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%"
               android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <style name="Animations">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/close_to_bottom</item>
    </style>
```

and the view is

```
    package com.creation.android.core.portrait_ui.common;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import com.creation.android.R;

public class PopUpView extends PopupWindow implements PopupWindow.OnDismissListener {

    public static final int POPUP_AUTO_DISMISS = 10 * 1000;
    private Context mContext;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isShowing()) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

    public PopUpView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setFocusable(true);
        mContext = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
        View contentView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.pop_up_menu_view, null);
        setContentView(contentView);
        setWidth(SCREEN_WIDTH);
        setHeight(SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        setOnDismissListener(this);

        setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations);
    }

    public void show(View view) {
        try {
            showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

            mHandler.postAtTime(mRunnable, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + POPUP_AUTO_DISMISS);
        } catch (WindowManager.BadTokenException e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Alpha Animation followed by Translate Animation and vice verse.

See this example:

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

final Animation aAnim1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
aAnim1.setFillAfter(true);
aAnim1.setRepeatCount(0);
aAnim1.setDuration(5000);

final Animation tAnim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -20.0f);
tAnim1.setFillAfter(true);
tAnim1.setRepeatCount(0);
tAnim1.setDuration(5000);
tAnim1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

final Animation aAnim2 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
aAnim2.setFillAfter(true);
aAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);
aAnim2.setDuration(5000);

final Animation tAnim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f,
        0.0f);
tAnim2.setFillAfter(true);
tAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);
tAnim2.setDuration(5000);
tAnim2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
aAnim1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        img.startAnimation(tAnim1);
    }
});

tAnim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        img.startAnimation(aAnim2);
    }
});

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        img.startAnimation(aAnim1);
    }
});
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        img.startAnimation(aAnim1);
    }
});
```

I have simply done this:

In button 1's click:

1. Make image visible - alpha 0 to 1.
2. Slide up - Translate using fromY 0.0f and toY -20.0f

In button 2's click:

3. Slide down - Translate using fromY -20.0f and toY 0.0f
4. Make image invisible again - alpha 1 to 0.

I have used animation listener for starting other animation while first is over. You can try using [Animator Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html), instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx. But i don't want this kind of animation. I wanted delay between two animation.

Comment: U can give delay before playing animation.

Answer (score 0):

Clear animation of view after onAnimationEnd method
Ex: Need to clear Textview(txtView) animation

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // Clear view animation
    txtView.clearAnimation();
}

});
```